# Postgres casting between varchar and double precision suddenly stopped working

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have been importing data into PostgreSQL tables all day using ogr2ogr and then spatially enabling the data with no issues up to now. I have been cutting and pasting the code and this is what I have been using:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN geom geometry(POINT,4326);
UPDATE mytable SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(cast (lon AS double precision),cast (lat AS double precision ) ),4326);
```

On the last table, I suddenly get this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "#VALUE!"
```

Nothing has changed, at least as far as I know, I was importing a csv file, same as all the others.

I checked the csv file for spaces or unusual characters but it looks in order

> > Column lon, lon are of type **character varying**

here is a sample of the data

```
id,name,name_alt,lat,lon,description
1,Abbott Seamount,,31.8,174.3,A seamount located north of Midway Islands (US) in the North Pacific Ocean; name origin unknown.
2,Abra Canyon,,17.51667,120.36667,An undersea canyon located off the northwest coast of the Philippine island of Luzon in the South China Sea; named after the Abra River
3,Abraham Canyon,Abraham Sea Valley,52.61667,172.33333,An undersea canyon in the area of the Aleutian Islands in the North Pacific Ocean; named in association with Abraham Bay; Attu Island; Alaska (US). 
4,Abrolhos Bank,,-18.5,38.75,A bank located off the coast of Brazil in the Atlantic Ocean; upon which sits the Arquipélago dos Abrolhos (archipelago). 
5,Abrolhos Seamounts,Abrolhos Ridge; Cadeia dos Abrolhos,-17.33333,36.5,Seamounts located off the coast of Brazil in the Atlantic Ocean; named in association with the Abrolhos Bank and Arquipélago dos Abrolhos (archipelago). 
6,Abubacer Ridge,,36.8,1.65,An undersea ridge located off the coast of Spain in the western Mediterranean Sea; named for Ibn Tufayl (known as Abubacer to Europeans); 12th-century Spanish-Arab philosopher and physician. 
7,Aby Canyon,,4.25,-3.66667,An undersea canyon located off the coast of Côte d'Ivoire; named in association with Lagune Aby; Côte d'Ivoire (lagoon)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it work without that last line? Have you checked all of the name and name_alt values for an embedded comma?

Comment: The first line works, the second line does not. I had excel do a global replace on the file and changed all commas to semi-colons. I have scanned the table visually as well and cannot see anything untoward either. It would have to be in the data, but why would it issue a syntax, or is that referring to the data. Character encoding is latin1 when imported, but I just noticed that the database is utf. I have about 100 tables in that database with no problem before.

Comment: Does it work if you change the semicolon in the first line description to something else (or just remove it)?

Comment: removed it, same error. was probably not a good choice to replace commas with in hindsight

Comment: Ok, found it. One # char towards the bottom of the file. Just happened to precede the word VALUE. OMG!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future users:

This problem was caused by bad data. There was the "#" Character on one cell of the csv that I missed that just happened to be the word "#VALUE!" (actually generated by someones formula at one stage I would guess)

The error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "#VALUE!"
```

was being reported by PostgreSQL as that exactly what it was seeing in the data, which was invalid. I had a lot of rows and just missed it.

Moral of the story, check your data carefully. If preparing CSV files for uploading and later GeoSpatial uses, sort on the **lat** and **lon** columns, that will show any non numeric values in there quickly.